# Differences in this Array Declarations in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, declaration, difference, between

What is the difference between declaring:

```
$myArray = Array();
```

and:

```
$myArray = [];
```

Comment: pretty sure `$myArray = new Array();` is not php

Comment: Question edited, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference, it's just two alternative syntaxes. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php